# unable to read and write htdocs folder in XAMPP

Tags: laravel, permissions, xampp

I am creating a laravel project within /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs.
I used following to apply the read and write privilege to htdocs folder in XAMPP folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 htdocs
```

Then I create the project within /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs

```
create-project laravel/laravel [Project Name]
```

It shows error

> Installing laravel/laravel (v5.6.12)
>   [ErrorException]
>     mkdir(): Permission denied

Does anyone know how to solve this problems?
Appreciate for the help

Updated:

I solved this problem by installing the lower version of XAMPP.

Comment: @Hussein, laravel did not recommend to do that. Yes, i try that before, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Change document root of the server.
I assume your xampp installation folder is

> /opt/lampp

Run `sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` on the terminal to edit `httpd.conf` file.

You have to change these two lines.

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">
```

Then change `/opt/lampp/htdocs` directory to any directory in your home folder for example `/home/yourUserName/htdocs`

**Note: Replace "yourUserName" with your username.**

After that, those two lines should look like

```
DocumentRoot "/home/yourUserName/htdocs"

<Directory "/home/yourUserName/htdocs">
```

After saving the changes run `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart` to restart **apache**

Now create local projects in your `/home/yourUserName/htdocs` directory without any permission problem.

Comment: my system is MacOS , not Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, I never used **MacOS** so I don't have any knowledge about that, if you change the document root of your server to any directory where you have all the permissions then you won't have any problem.

I'll delete my answer after you've seen my comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chmod 777 htdocs
```

You should use -R if you are allowing a file. You shouldn't use -R if you are allowing a folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should open the htdocs folder as root and it will now allow you to create a directory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).